# Why does this coroutine implementation for std::optional not work?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine, stdoptional

I took the implementation of coroutines for std::future from the documentation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_traits and modified it for std::optional

```cpp
#include <coroutine>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

 
template <typename T, typename... Args>
requires(!std::is_void_v<T> && !std::is_reference_v<T>)
struct std::coroutine_traits<std::optional<T>, Args...> {
  struct promise_type : std::optional<T> {
 
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }

    std::optional<T> get_return_object() noexcept {
      return *this;
    }
 
    void return_value(const T &value)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>) {
        **this = value;
    }
    void return_value(T &&value)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) {
      **this = std::move(value);
    }
    void unhandled_exception() noexcept {
    }
  };
};

template <typename T>
auto operator co_await(std::optional<T> optional) noexcept
requires(!std::is_reference_v<T>) {
  struct awaiter : std::optional<T> {
    bool await_ready() const noexcept {
        return static_cast<bool>(*this);
    }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> cont) const {
        cont.destroy();
    }
    T await_resume() { return **this; }
  };
  return awaiter{std::move(optional)};
}



void process(std::string msg, std::optional<int> x)
{
    if(x)
        std::cout << msg  << " has value " << * x << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << msg  << " no value" << std::endl; 
}

std::optional<int> comput(std::optional<int> a, std::optional<int> b)
{
    int c = (co_await a) * (co_await b);
    process("inner", c);
    co_return c;
}

std::optional<int> gen(){
    co_return 15;
}

int main(){

    process("final 0", gen());
    process("final 1", comput(10, 11));
    process("final 2", comput(std::nullopt, 11));
    process("final 3", comput(10, std::nullopt));
    process("final 4", comput(10, 33));

}
```

The results look like

```
final 0 no value
inner has value 110
final 1 no value
final 2 no value
final 3 no value
inner has value 330
final 4 no value
```

I would have expected the results to look like

```
final 15 no value
inner has value 110
final 1 has value 110
final 2 no value
final 3 no value
inner has value 330
final 4 has value 330
```

It seems to be *almost* working because the output of the temporary generated by the lines is correct.

```cpp
int c = (co_await a) * (co_await b);
process("inner", c);
```

Godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/Woah8K5rE

Comment: Did you miss the `as_coroutine` part of the example?

Comment: I didn't quite see the point of that and it all compiled without it. But just to be sure I created a version with it included and the same issue occurs. https://godbolt.org/z/fGfYc9vxa

Comment: You cannot specialize any standard library template unless you are doing so with respect to at least one user-defined type. Attempting to do so yields UB. That's not what's wrong with your code, but it is still incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very significant difference between your implementation and what you're linking to.

In the cppreference example, note that:

- `coroutine_traits` is being specialized for `std::future<T>`, which `get_return_object()` returns.
- the `promise_type` inherits from `std::promise<T>`.

Those are different types - `promise<T>` and `future<T>`. Which, internally, are linked:

```cpp
std::future<T> get_return_object() noexcept {
    return this->get_future();
}
```

The `future<T>` returned from `this->get_future()` has shared state with `this`, so that when we do `this->set_value(value)`, the `future` sees that.

---

In your implementation, you're specializing `coroutine_traits` on `std::optional<T>` and then (I'm simplifying slightly):

```cpp
std::optional<T> get_return_object() noexcept { return *this; }
 
void return_value(const T &value) { **this = value; }
```

This is wrong for two reasons:

1. First, the `return_object` here is just a completely distinct object of type `std::optional<T>` that your `promise_type` never has access to again, so you can never mutate it. Since the return object is just some distinct, disengaged optional that you don't have access to again, you just always get a disengaged optional back.
2. `**this = value;` is simply wrong - if the current `optional<T>` is disengaged (which it is), this is dereferencing a disengaged optional.

In order to get this to work, your `promise_type` needs to have a way to mutate the *returned* `std::optional<T>`. And then, after that, you need to set the value properly.

Comment: I think the conclusion needs some clarifying. For this code to work, the object from `get_return_object` *can't* be a `std::optional`, since as you say the promise object won't be able to mutate it. You need to return something that *isn't* a `std::optional` from `get_return_object` (which may implicitly convert to `std::optional`), which holds a reference to the real data managed by the `promise_type`.

Comment: The explanation seems reasonable so I tried it out by creating a proxy. https://godbolt.org/z/vY7ecKP8b but the result doesn't change. Though now I'm not really sure about the lifetimes. The pointer might be dangling.

Comment: This finally works but I had to use a shared_ptr to hold the optional which seems like a huge overhead. https://godbolt.org/z/dq8W7E6rq

Comment: @Barry That looks super scary. You take the address of a member of a stack allocated object and then return that object and hope that the compiler elides the copy and that the user makes no other copies. Is this really safe?

Comment: @Barry NVRO is not mandatory. Your code is not safe!

Comment: @HTNW It's safe per Itanium ABI. I mean, you could do it [this way instead](https://godbolt.org/z/8GnrhrxTv), but either way you need to ensure that `shared_optional` isn't trivial.

Comment: @Barry It seems to work under gcc 12.2 https://godbolt.org/z/fsb6bbGfv but it doesn't work under clang 15.0 https://godbolt.org/z/8Ev1f4Yhn

Comment: I suspect that  you are correct that the object is created on the stack of the caller and asking for the address gets you what you think you ask for. *However* I suspect there is no guarantee within the coroutine ABI that there are no intermediate copies of the object returned by *return_object* before it is returned to the user. If intermediate copies are made then the pointer doesn't point to the correct object anymore.

Comment: The NRVO version is not required to work, but the RVO/guaranteed elision version is safe. The Clang/GCC difference is https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2563.html.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for that. The linked issue even explicitly mentions the clang bug is an impediment to implementing coroutines for std::optional https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56532#issue-1305293263 I guess I will wait a little longer before trying out such things in production code.